# Scroll RecyclerView on drag and drop before item is out of view's bounds

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview

I've implemented drag and drop on a recyclerview using SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback.

How would I cause the recyclerview to scroll before the dragged item is out of bounds?

Comment: If someone is looking for this sort of behaviour, there is a good library called [advancedrecyclerview](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview). The library mimics the drag and drop behaviour found in Play Music